# Sorting List of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes where I add a total values in each column for each dataframes.
Then I want to sort all dataframes by that total.

Here's an example but I'm really iterating over them. I set the index to the first column before making the list, maybe something there?

Code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Charge1', 2.0], ['Charge2', 5.5], ['Charge3', 80.7,]]),
                   columns=['Event', 'Charge'])
df1[['Charge']] = df1[['Charge']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Charge1', 62], ['Charge2', 55], ['Charge3', 38,]]),
                   columns=['Event', 'Charge'])
df2[['Charge']] = df2[['Charge']].apply(pd.to_numeric)              

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Charge1', 456], ['Charge2', 155.454], ['Charge3', 38.8452,]]),
                   columns=['Event', 'Charge'])
df3[['Charge']] = df3[['Charge']].apply(pd.to_numeric)  

df1 = df1.append(df1.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.replace(np.nan, 'Total', regex=True)

df2 = df2.append(df2.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
df2 = df2.replace(np.nan, 'Total', regex=True)

df3 = df3.append(df3.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
df3 = df3.replace(np.nan, 'Total', regex=True)

df1 = df1.set_index([df1.columns[0]])
df2 = df2.set_index([df2.columns[0]])
df3 = df3.set_index([df3.columns[0]])


df_list = [df1,df2,df3]
```

I've tried things like:

`sorted_dflist = sorted(df_list, key = lambda x: x[x.columns[-1]])`

Which produces this error *ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*

or

`sorteddflist= sorted(df_list,key=lambda x:x["Total"].max(axis=0))`

where I get a KeyError for Total

Thoughts?

Comment: Your second attempt worked fine for me `sorteddflist= sorted(df_list,key=lambda x:x["Total"].max(axis=0))`. Are you certain each dataframe has a column named "Total"?

Comment: Strange, I copied the code from my post and then the 2nd one, still getting the KeyError.  I see Total in them.  I tried even before and after setting the indices. If I view em all, I see Total.

Comment: Why do you have them on a list instead of in a single dataframe with an extra index level?... as returned by `pd.concat(list, keys=df_names)`

Comment: The background of this is that I'm gathering data on accounts.  The final outcome shows these account usages in an email with each DF separate.  Just want to sort it so the most usage accounts is on top of the email

Comment: `sorteddflist= sorted(df_list,key=lambda x:x.loc["Total"].max(axis=0))` did you tried this?

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code to sort the list ascending:

`sorteddflist= sorted(df_list,key=lambda x:x.loc["Total"].max(axis=0))`

Code to set it descending:

`sorteddflist= sorted(df_list,key=lambda x:x.loc["Total"].max(axis=0),reverse=True)`