# Apply sorting to a list of dataframes Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, sorting

I've struggling trying to insert a **sorting** in this code:

```
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.CSV") # To get all csv files disorganized
all_csv = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files] # List of dataframes

# I want to sort it by the values of the first column of each dataframe in the all_csv list.

for f in all_csv:
    goal = pd.DataFrame.sort_values(by=(f.iloc[:,0])) #Maybe something like this??
```

So, Anyone has an idea how can I do this? I've looking on other post but does not apply to a undefined column name (a.k.a. f.iloc[:,0] ) or a list of dataframes (I also thought of using dictionaries but I'd like to see if is posible to use with lists).

Thank you :)

May be useful this ideas: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531369/sorting-list-of-dataframes), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242239/applying-an-operation-on-a-list-of-dataframes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index `df.columns` for individual dataframes:

```
goal = df.sort_values(by=df.columns[0])
```

For the entire list of dataframes, you can use list comprehension:

```
all_csv = [df.sort_values(by=df.columns[0]) for df in all_csv]
```

Suppose you had a dataframe that looked like:

```
   a  b
0  2  1
1  3  2
2  1  3
```

Then when you run:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=df.columns[0])
```

`df` becomes:

```
   a  b
2  1  3
0  2  1
1  3  2
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses enke's code to sort each dataframe by the first column, but returns all dataframes in a list as you requested:

`all_csv  = [df.sort_values(by=df.columns[0]) for df in all_csv]`